# Can't connect to Redis server using ASP.NET Session State Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, redis

I have been attempting to replace ASP.NET Session with Redis for some time now. Multiple hours with the [Microsoft ASP.NET Session State Provider for Redis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/announcing-asp-net-session-state-provider-for-redis-preview-release.aspx) have been fruitless.

We have an on-premises Sentinel configuration for Redis. Originally I thought this was not working due to the Provider not supporting Sentinels. I switched my connection string to use the master, in hopes that I would at least be able to establish a connection. Still nothing.

I have tried multiple configurations for this provider and continually receive either "No connection available for the request" or "Additional information: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING."

Here are some of the configurations I've attempted:

Attempt #1:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="RedisConnection" connectionString="1.2.3.4:5,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=XXXXXX,ConnectTimeout=10000"/>
</connectionStrings>

<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionString="RedisConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Attempt #2:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="1.2.3.4" port="5" accessKey="XXXXXXX" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Attempt #3:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="1.2.3.4:5" accessKey="XXXXXXX" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I have found very little documentation on this provider, and troubleshooting has been a challenge. I came across a third-party provider and decided to try it, compared to the Microsoft provider.

I was able to successfully connect with [Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore](https://github.com/TheCloudlessSky/Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore), using the following configuration:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" type="Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore.RedisSessionStateStoreProvider" host="PASSWORD@1.2.3.4:5" clientType="pooled" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

With this is mind, what is the correct format for a connection string for the Microsoft provider? It will be easier for me to receive internal support from a first party library, and at this point, it would be a moral victory to get this working.

Also, if anyone knows how I could configure this to hit the Sentinel and determine the master instance to connect to, I would welcome a blog post or any sort of knowledge share on the topic.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Azure Redis Cache? or a local/cloud custom server?

Comment: Local, custom server.

Comment: I'd try to replicate your scenario. Is your redis instance running on Windows? Wich OS versión?

Comment: This is a running on a Linux box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can give you an example of a working configuration, which we have in our production, no sentinel, but directly to the master:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="Custom_RedisSessionStateStore">
    <providers>
    <add name="Custom_RedisSessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="your_host_name_goes_here" accessKey="" port="6379" ssl="false" operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why, but that works! It has to be the ssl=false flag. I had been setting it to true based on some other documentation I found on another error I was receiving. Doh! Now if I could figure out how to get this to run with Sentinels...